# Split item in list while keeping the order

Tags: list, f#

I have a list of items looking something like this:

```
let myList = [ "One"; "Two"; "Three and Four"; "Five"; "and Six"; "Seven and"; "Nine and Ten and Eleven" ]
```

I need to split every item containing the word `and` into separate items and re-insert them into the list, while keeping the order. Is there any elegant and efficient way how to do this? Currently I am using a loop and mutable list for aggregation:

```
let mutable result = []
for item in myList do
  let split = item.Split("and", StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
  for subItem in split do
    result <- subItem::result
    
List.rev result
```

I have a suspicion that there is a better way to do this (more functional, less C#-y), but I cannot find out how to do it.

Comment: Aside from the actual problem, splitting at "and" is no good because you'll treat "Thousand" wrong. Split at " and ", " and" and "and ", or split at space and interpret "and", or use regex to do it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Some one better at FP might come and improve this because I am also still learning things
but here is my take.

```ml
let myList = [ "One"; "Two"; "Three and Four"; "Five"; "and Six"; "Seven and"; "Nine and Ten and Eleven" ]

myList
|> Seq.collect (fun x -> x.Split("and", StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries))
|> Seq.toList
```

Comment: Thank you, I was not aware of the `collect` function. F# has really a large array of useful built-in functions.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: `Seq.concat` is your friend. You still need to convert back to `List`.

Answer (score 1):

Here is one way of doing it - write a recursive function that goes throug each element, splits it and appends the resulting list to the accumulator.

```
open System
let myList = [ "One"; "Two"; "Three and Four"; "Five"; "and Six"; "Seven and"; "Nine and Ten and Eleven" ]

let split (s: string) = s.Split([|"and"|], StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries) |> Array.toList

let splititems (lst : string list) = 
    let rec run acc l = 
        match l with
        | x::xs -> 
                let up = (split x)::acc
                run up xs
        | [] -> acc

    let res = run [] lst 
    res |> List.concat |> List.rev
```

Another way is to use the List.foldBack:

```
List.foldBack (fun str acc -> (split str)::acc) myList [] |> List.concat
```

Both approaches return list of lists, so you need to call List.concat to merge them together.